# html.hiddenfor error when rendering view outside controller as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, render

I need server side page render (without request) outside controller(I want to render view outside controller). 
To do that, i need a fake  `HttpRequest` to create `ControllerContext` so i can render view with `razor.Render()` and return
`stringWriter.ToString()` to client using signalr hub.

So i used this code to render partialview as string;

```
public class FakeController : Controller   { }

HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", new UriBuilder("http", "localhost", 10654, "/" + "SomeController/SomeAction").Uri.ToString(), "");
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("Controller", "SomeController");
routeData.Values.Add("Action", "SomeAction");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
HttpContext httpContextMock = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
var _contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContextMock);

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(_contextWrapper , routeData), new FakeController());

string filePath = "~/Areas/Site/Views/Shared/SomePartialView.cshtml";
var razor = new RazorView(controllerContext, filePath, null, false, null);

razor.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, razor, new ViewDataDictionary(model), new TempDataDictionary(), stringWriter), stringWriter);
return stringWriter.ToString();
```

Here when code tries to render `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.property)`

**I get error;**

```
source : System.Web.WebPages 
error  : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

But the weird thing is that i can get `@Model.property` value(i mean it is not null) and also the other model properties(And it seems that only @Html.HiddenFor or @Html.Hidden is the problem).

Comment: what is in `model.property`?

Comment: did you try to give it a value `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.property, "");`, it shouldn't be the issue, but try nothing to lose

Comment: @jamiedanq model.property is a string value

Comment: @Munzer nothing changed...